# Is there any way to guide what class a rookie will become?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

As far as I can tell, the game decides what class my guys will be promoted to upon receiving their first promotion. Are there any ways to influence this decision?

Right now I'm stuck with more snipers than I know what to do with, and still only have a single Heavy and Assault each. If I had played these soldiers differently when they were rookies, would they have been promoted to different classes?

If that is the case, what playstyle can I try to self-enforce in order to get the promotion that I want? Or is it just utterly random?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

According to readings around the internet - no official sources - it's random.  In my experience it has been random.  I think I've gotten 2 heavies, 3 snipers, 3 support, and 2 assaults (still have a few rookies yet to get tested out).  How many guys have you seen promoted?

Note that I play rookies exactly one way: move closer to enemies.  Draw fire.  Go through doors first.  Shoot or capture if possible.  Pat on back if they survive the mission.  ;)

Comment: @yx. Funny. I've been doing the opposite with my rookies. The big guys with more health take a hit if necessary and the rookies move in for the kill so they can develop into useful soldiers.

Comment: @StrixVaria pssssh, you can coddle your rookies all you want but a REAL soldier is tempered by fighting off a mind eating Chrysalid with nothing but a stick (and long distance fire support from your heavies).

Comment: @yx you are wise.  I plan to name my next two rookies after you and StrixVaria, and you will get to hide behind him.  ;)

Comment: @yx. a rookie will benefit a lot more from the XP killing an enemy brings than a colonel.

Comment: I'm currently working on a game where I worked through my initial allotment of rookies and got one support (KIA a few missions later on an unlucky shot) and two assaults.  I hired three more rookies and promoted another (useless) sniper.  _Grumble._

Comment: @Jon Ericson - Snipers are amazing.

Comment: @peacedog: Hmmm...  I wonder if a squad of snipers would work?  At any rate there's a law of diminishing returns.  When you already have 4, a 5th one is a lot less useful.

Comment: Ahhh, I misinterpreted your comment.

Comment: @peacedog Snipers are amazing...once they reach colonel. Until they reach colonel, they get in about half as many shots...most of those either with a pistol, or with a -20% to hit penalty that makes them miss more often than any other class. The extra shots early from assaults and heavies make them so much more useful...not to mention giving them more XP faster. "Snipers" in the original X-Com had squad sight, could move and shoot with no penalty to aim, and had double tap from the first turn of the game. With no close-range penalty. Biggest nerf ever.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock In my experience, snipers are only markedly worse at the Squaddie level. Once you give them Squadsight they're very useful, at least outside of really constricted maps. If you're literally taking most of your snipers' shots with the pistol, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @peacedog Give 'em a red shirt, why dontcha!

Comment: @Alex they should just come that way, to drop all pretense!

Answer (score 11):

You could try saving your game before ending a mission, and then reloading to get a different promotion.

I got this idea after a PC crash. I loaded and repeated the last action, and 2 rookies became an assault and sniper instead of the heavy and heavy they were previously.

Comment: Seems like a legit usage of save scumming.

Answer (score 5):

## They are completely random.

I got 3 sniper once and in the next mission 3 supports... I think that my game just like to troll me...

From [wiki](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/XCOM_Wiki):

### [Rookie](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Rookie_%28rank%29)

> A Rookie is a fresh Soldier who lacks a class. After going out onto
> missions and gaining a small amount of experience (approximately one
> kills worth), they receive the Squaddie rank and are randomly given
> one of the four classes: Assault, Heavy, Sniper, or Support

### [Assault](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Assault_Class)

> Rookie promotion is slightly weighted toward classes you have less of,
> but promotion is otherwise completely random.

### [Heavy](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Heavy_Class)

> Rookie promotion is slightly weighted toward classes you have less of,
> but promotion is otherwise completely random.

### [Sniper](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Sniper_Class)

> Rookie promotion is slightly weighted toward classes you have less of,
> but promotion is otherwise completely random.

### [Support](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Support_Class)

> Rookie promotion is slightly weighted toward classes you have less of,
> but promotion is otherwise completely random.

### [Psionic](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Psionic_Class)

> Soldiers belonging to any of the principle four classes can access the
> abilities of this sub-class in addition to the abilities they already
> own, however these psi-abilities only unlock for soldiers who possess
> "The Gift" which is determined by testing in the Psionic Labs.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to buy the Training school upgrade that allows you to hire soldiers as squaddies instead of recruits. It's still random, but every 10 creds you spend gets you a soldier with a **class**, rather than a recruit you need to survive a mission. Either spend lots of money or reload and rebuy the soldiers til you get what you want - its your choice!

Answer (score 1):

In every case in which I have remembered to check, my first four recruits always became one of each class (in other words, I never got two of a class while still having zero of another class.) That *may* be a co-incidence. After that it appears to be random.

Comment: I've definitely had duplicates from the first four.

Answer (score 1):

I think its governed by there aim ability in my experience.
a 75 aim rookie becomes sniper, 50 aim rookie assault with stupid shotgun!
arapho

Answer (score 0):

Only the first 4 rookies that you get will be fixed to be one of each class (or 3 if you are playing with tutorial; you'll already have a heavy). If you get one injured without leveling and switch out, then the new recruit you use won't be placed under same restriction; has to be the original. Not sure what happens if you get the rookie killed.

Oherwise only psionics are influenced by will, but that has nothing to do with rookies.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that I was able to influence the class assigned to a few of my soldiers.  I wanted to gets couple support members, so I brought a med kit and made sure it was the first action for that unit.  Later in the mission I used them to finish off an injured enemy at mid range.  During the mission I had them shadow a more advanced team mate for defense and to provide convenience for using the med kit when needed.  At the end of the mission - low and behold, the class assigned was support.  It's possible that it was coincidence, but I was able to accomplish this with three support units.  Just now I was able to successfully get an assault class assignment by making 2 (or maybe it was 3) kills at 1-2 tile range.  Equipped him with Plasma Rifle, Plasma Pistol, Nano Vest, and Titan Armor.  Dudes that I had him finish off were all Mutons.  I didn't have him attack other than to finalize a kill at super-close range.

Answer (score -3):

In my experience getting a long-range kill makes a rookie a sniper, short range is an assault, grenades or another type of kill is a heavy, and getting no kills will earn a support.

I rarely use grenades and have only two heavies out of twenty soldiers. My rookies rarely score kills and I have like eight supports.

This has not been confirmed by any source besides my own experience and a wiki article.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to go off of more than a rumor on the wiki before I change the checkmark over to a different answer. I am very interested in the results of testing in this regard, however.

Comment: I never, ever used grenades or rockets. I got almost even numbers of each class - 4, 4, 3, and 3 (in some order) out of 14 soldiers. Also, this answer doesn't mesh with the upgrade that makes new soldiers squaddies.

Comment: I just got a rookie promoted to assault with zero kills, so this theory looks pretty much disproved.

Comment: I know it was probably not true, it was just something I read on the wiki and that I was experiencing. Ah well.

Answer (score -4):

It may seem like it is totally random but it is not i recently got a rookie and his only kill of the mission was a mid range kill that was a crit as well and he became a sniper.

I also previously have had large amounts of deaths in the other class on mine in early game so my game I thing leans little bit away from snipers since I got the new guy perk i have been getting more snipers and less of everything else when I hit late game

Comment: I don't think a single rookie turning into a sniper after a mid-range crit kill is a sufficient sample size to determine probability from.